# decimals not showing correctly c++

Tags: c++

Hey everyone so my c++ code isnt properly showing my decimal values. Here's what I have

```
int sum = 0;
for (vector<int>::iterator it = vint.begin(); it != vint.end(); it++)
{
    sum += *it;
}
float average = (sum / 10000);
cout.precision(5);
cout.setf(std::ios::fixed);
cout << "Average: " << average << endl;
```

the sum is random cause of my code but its usually around 506782, etc.
but my ouput is

OUTPUT: 
50.0000

help please

Comment: Search the internet for "C++ integer division".  For example, 1/3 == 0; but 1.0/3.0 == 3.333333333333.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are performing an integer division (both `sum` and `10000` are integers). The result will always be a truncated integer (e.g., 5 / 2 == 2). If you make the constant `10000` into a floating point constant (`10000.0f`), a floating point division will be performed instead. This should fix it:

```
int sum = 0;
for (vector<int>::iterator it = vint.begin(); it != vint.end(); it++) {
    sum += *it;
}
float average = (sum / 10000.0f);
cout.precision(5);
cout.setf(std::ios::fixed);
cout << "Average: " << average << endl;
```

Comment: You should include text in your answer describing *how* you fixed it.  Don't only give answers, as that doesn't help people learn.

Comment: I know I am still editing.

Answer (score 0):

You should cast the sum into float. When you do sum/10000, the result is an integer with decimal spaces truncated.

```
int sum = 0;
for (vector<int>::iterator it = vint.begin(); it != vint.end(); it++)
{
    sum += *it;
}
float average = ((float)sum / 10000);
cout.precision(5);
cout.setf(std::ios::fixed);
cout << "Average: " << average << endl;
```